How to query a data using DateTime format while the data stored in table is in Unix Timestamp?
on Amazon Athena, I have my table:



name
server_time
register




Rudy
1718251764
Yes


John
1718294964
Yes


Charles
1718035764
Yes



Instead of have to go unixtimestamp web to get the Unix Timestamp for my desired date, I want to filter the table using YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM in my query. is it actually possible to do so? if it's not, is it possible to do it on jupyter-notebook?
Honestly, I'm not sure which SQL is used on Amazon Athena. I tried :

SQL Server

SELECT *
FROM my_table
where server_time between datediff(second,'1970-01-01','2024-06-12') and datediff(second,'1970-01-01','2024-06-13')

I got error Column 'second' cannot be resolved or requester is not authorized to access requested resources. Also tried datediff_big still not works.

MySQL

SELECT *
FROM my_table
where server_time between unix_timestamp('2024-06-12') and unix_timestamp('2024-06-13')

I got error Function 'unix_timestamp' not registered

SQLite

SELECT *
FROM my_table
where server_time between unixepoch('2024-06-12') and unixepoch('2024-06-13')

I got error Function 'unix_timestamp' not registered

Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52011616/10376537

Look at this post, is this what you are trying to do in Athena? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42927726/converting-unix-epoch-time-to-extended-iso8601

You can use AWS Athena UI to to write your queries. The online editor has almost all the features that a modern tool has. There is no need to install any plugin. Navigate to Athena from AWS console. From the beginning of Athena, the query engine under the hood was Trino  and you can go through trino documents to get syntax https://trino.io/docs/current/functions.html
Coming to question you asked, you can use following query to convert your unix time to datetime in string format and then filter out
with cte as (
select 'Rudy' as name, 1718251764 as server_time, 'Yes' as register 
union all 
select 'John' as name, 1718294964 as server_time, 'Yes' as register 
union all 
select 'Charles' as name, 1718035764 as server_time, 'Yes' as register 
)
select *, format_datetime(from_unixtime(server_time), 'Y-MM-dd HH:MM') as date_str from cte
where format_datetime(from_unixtime(server_time), 'Y-MM-dd HH:MM') <= '2024-06-13 05:05'

yes you can use Jupyterlab to query athena but you need to install boto3 and configure AWS credentials and subsequently create instance of athena client and use appropriate functions to get query results and following link should be of help https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena/client/start_query_execution.html

thank you @sandeep007
the query it's not what I'm looking for but your answer regarding AWS Athena and Trino leads me to the answer. I found my answer from Presto SQL: TO_UNIXTIME.
